# d3 chord diagram that produces parallel ribbons

Tags: d3.js, chord-diagram

I currently am working with a chord layout, I would like to have my chords parallel though (illustrated with red overlays).

How do I accomplish this? I tried the different sorting options and none seem to yield the desired results.

[image]

code:

```
var width = 1000;
var height = 600;

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");

var matrix5x5 = [
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],   
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],   
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]            
];
var range5 = ["#848484", "#848484", "#848484", "#848484", "#848484", "#848484", "848484", "848484"];

var chord = d3.layout.chord()
        .padding(0.1)
        .matrix(matrix5x5);

var fill = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(range5.length))
        .range(range5);


var innerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * .39;
var outerRadius = innerRadius * 1.1;

svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(chord.groups)
        .enter().append("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return fill(d.index);
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return fill(d.index);
        })
        .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius))
        .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
        .on("mouseout", fade(1));

svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "chord")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(chord.chords)
        .enter().append("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return fill(d.target.index);
        })
        .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(innerRadius))
        .style("opacity", 1);

var range5_artists = ["All", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"];

svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(chord.groups)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
            return range5_artists[d.index];
        })
      .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
            + "translate(" + (innerRadius + 35) + ")"
            + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
      })
.style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
        .attr("font-size", "11px")
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return  range5[d.index];
        })
        .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
        .on("mouseout", fade(1));


function fade(opacity) {
    return function(g, i) {
        svg.selectAll("g.chord path")
                .filter(function(d) {
                    return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i;
                })
                .transition()
                .style("opacity", opacity);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for here is the [`.sortSubGroups()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Chord-Layout#wiki-sortSubgroups). You want to sort based on index, but this information isn't passed to the comparator. So we use a dirty trick that relies on the order of evaluation and always return 1.

Result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bn897/).

Comment: if i update the fiddle with an expanded matrix, the function you pasted no longer applies the logic correctly, see [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/max_powers/Bn897/1/)

Comment: No, as I've said, this is only a dirty trick. Your data doesn't really lend itself to sorting because all the values passed in are the same. What you would need to do is define an array of sorting comparison results (i.e. 1 and -1) in the order that the chords will be iterated over and return from that.