# D3.js Chord Diagram: Avoid overlapping of adjacent (non-crossing) chords

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, chord-diagram

I am developing a D3.js chord diagram to visualize people flows between different areas of an airport. When clicking an an area's outer arch, only the chords running to that arch are shown.
I am now getting to the fine touches of it and am lacking any clues on how to approach one design problem.

Here's the photoshop-made target I am aiming for:
[image: Target chord diagram]

I did find a solution for the problem of chords crossing each other (using this excellent blog post https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2016/06/orientation-gradient-d3-chord-diagram), but the problem I am now still having, is that adjacent chords still overlap:

[image: Overlapping chords]

This just looks really hideous and I would very much like to avoid this from happening, however I've got no clue on how to achieve this... Is this possible with d3.js? (I am currently using v3, as the "avoid chords from crossing" hack is customizing d3.js v3 source files). Otherwise, where might I be able to be customize d3 to change the shape of the chords?

Edit: I want to emphasize, that I have figured out the problem of chord ORDERING, this is already correct, the chords do not cross each other, but still overlap. Here is an illustration to clarify my problem:
[image]

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t2g3je69/

```js
var locations = [
  { id: 0, name: "Gate A", color: "#12B32D" },
  { id: 1, name: "Gate B", color: "#0D8020" },
  { id: 2, name: "Gate D", color: "#095916" },
  { id: 3, name: "Gate E", color: "#064010" },
  { id: 4, name: "Check-in 1", color: "#F4CF11" },
  { id: 5, name: "Check-in 2", color: "#B3970C" },
  { id: 6, name: "Check-in 3", color: "#665607" },
  { id: 7, name: "Airside Center", color: "#0D6180" },
  { id: 8, name: "Airport Shopping", color: "#16A2D5" },
  { id: 9, name: "P1", color: "#01FAF1" },
  { id: 10, name: "P2", color: "#14CCCC" },
  { id: 11, name: "P3", color: "#0F9999" },
  { id: 12, name: "P4", color: "#0C8080" },
  { id: 13, name: "P5", color: "#074D4D" },
  { id: 14, name: "Rail", color: "#F27900" },
  { id: 15, name: "Bus/Tram", color: "#EF4F00" }
];

var flows = [
  { from: 0, to: 0, quantity: 428 },
  { from: 0, to: 1, quantity: 5 },
  { from: 0, to: 2, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 0, to: 3, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 0, to: 4, quantity: 1 },
  { from: 0, to: 5, quantity: 8 },
  { from: 0, to: 6, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 0, to: 7, quantity: 86 },
  { from: 0, to: 8, quantity: 318 },
  { from: 0, to: 9, quantity: 30 },
  { from: 0, to: 10, quantity: 23 },
  { from: 0, to: 11, quantity: 67 },
  { from: 0, to: 12, quantity: 101 },
  { from: 0, to: 13, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 0, to: 14, quantity: 270 },
  { from: 0, to: 15, quantity: 120 },
  { from: 1, to: 0, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 1, to: 1, quantity: 128 },
  { from: 1, to: 2, quantity: 40 },
  { from: 1, to: 3, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 1, to: 4, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 1, to: 5, quantity: 30 },
  { from: 1, to: 6, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 1, to: 7, quantity: 78 },
  { from: 1, to: 8, quantity: 172 },
  { from: 1, to: 9, quantity: 90 },
  { from: 1, to: 10, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 1, to: 11, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 1, to: 12, quantity: 13 },
  { from: 1, to: 13, quantity: 56 },
  { from: 1, to: 14, quantity: 134 },
  { from: 1, to: 15, quantity: 87 },
  { from: 2, to: 0, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 2, to: 1, quantity: 3 },
  { from: 2, to: 2, quantity: 97 },
  { from: 2, to: 3, quantity: 7 },
  { from: 2, to: 4, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 2, to: 5, quantity: 9 },
  { from: 2, to: 6, quantity: 3 },
  { from: 2, to: 7, quantity: 11 },
  { from: 2, to: 8, quantity: 109 },
  { from: 2, to: 9, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 2, to: 10, quantity: 3 },
  { from: 2, to: 11, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 2, to: 12, quantity: 9 },
  { from: 2, to: 13, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 2, to: 14, quantity: 76 },
  { from: 2, to: 15, quantity: 26 },
  { from: 3, to: 0, quantity: 3 },
  { from: 3, to: 1, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 3, to: 2, quantity: 9 },
  { from: 3, to: 3, quantity: 390 },
  { from: 3, to: 4, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 3, to: 5, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 3, to: 6, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 3, to: 7, quantity: 43 },
  { from: 3, to: 8, quantity: 126 },
  { from: 3, to: 9, quantity: 207 },
  { from: 3, to: 10, quantity: 23 },
  { from: 3, to: 11, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 3, to: 12, quantity: 36 },
  { from: 3, to: 13, quantity: 78 },
  { from: 3, to: 14, quantity: 532 },
  { from: 3, to: 15, quantity: 265 },
  { from: 4, to: 0, quantity: 165 },
  { from: 4, to: 1, quantity: 277 },
  { from: 4, to: 2, quantity: 80 },
  { from: 4, to: 3, quantity: 109 },
  { from: 4, to: 4, quantity: 78 },
  { from: 4, to: 5, quantity: 34 },
  { from: 4, to: 6, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 4, to: 7, quantity: 23 },
  { from: 4, to: 8, quantity: 381 },
  { from: 4, to: 9, quantity: 40 },
  { from: 4, to: 10, quantity: 35 },
  { from: 4, to: 11, quantity: 21 },
  { from: 4, to: 12, quantity: 54 },
  { from: 4, to: 13, quantity: 3 },
  { from: 4, to: 14, quantity: 38 },
  { from: 4, to: 15, quantity: 38 },
  { from: 5, to: 0, quantity: 80 },
  { from: 5, to: 1, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 5, to: 2, quantity: 5 },
  { from: 5, to: 3, quantity: 254 },
  { from: 5, to: 4, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 5, to: 5, quantity: 97 },
  { from: 5, to: 6, quantity: 22 },
  { from: 5, to: 7, quantity: 35 },
  { from: 5, to: 8, quantity: 103 },
  { from: 5, to: 9, quantity: 67 },
  { from: 5, to: 10, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 5, to: 11, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 5, to: 12, quantity: 6 },
  { from: 5, to: 13, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 5, to: 14, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 5, to: 15, quantity: 8 },
  { from: 6, to: 0, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 6, to: 1, quantity: 220 },
  { from: 6, to: 2, quantity: 70 },
  { from: 6, to: 3, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 6, to: 4, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 6, to: 5, quantity: 8 },
  { from: 6, to: 6, quantity: 238 },
  { from: 6, to: 7, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 6, to: 8, quantity: 3 },
  { from: 6, to: 9, quantity: 30 },
  { from: 6, to: 10, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 6, to: 11, quantity: 38 },
  { from: 6, to: 12, quantity: 8 },
  { from: 6, to: 13, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 6, to: 14, quantity: 20 },
  { from: 6, to: 15, quantity: 7 },
  { from: 7, to: 0, quantity: 87 },
  { from: 7, to: 1, quantity: 20 },
  { from: 7, to: 2, quantity: 123 },
  { from: 7, to: 3, quantity: 143 },
  { from: 7, to: 4, quantity: 9 },
  { from: 7, to: 5, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 7, to: 6, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 7, to: 7, quantity: 457 },
  { from: 7, to: 8, quantity: 30 },
  { from: 7, to: 9, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 7, to: 10, quantity: 32 },
  { from: 7, to: 11, quantity: 19 },
  { from: 7, to: 12, quantity: 3 },
  { from: 7, to: 13, quantity: 4 },
  { from: 7, to: 14, quantity: 73 },
  { from: 7, to: 15, quantity: 25 },
  { from: 8, to: 0, quantity: 120 },
  { from: 8, to: 1, quantity: 38 },
  { from: 8, to: 2, quantity: 96 },
  { from: 8, to: 3, quantity: 167 },
  { from: 8, to: 4, quantity: 3 },
  { from: 8, to: 5, quantity: 23 },
  { from: 8, to: 6, quantity: 9 },
  { from: 8, to: 7, quantity: 47 },
  { from: 8, to: 8, quantity: 97 },
  { from: 8, to: 9, quantity: 123 },
  { from: 8, to: 10, quantity: 86 },
  { from: 8, to: 11, quantity: 90 },
  { from: 8, to: 12, quantity: 34 },
  { from: 8, to: 13, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 8, to: 14, quantity: 176 },
  { from: 8, to: 15, quantity: 192 },
  { from: 9, to: 0, quantity: 30 },
  { from: 9, to: 1, quantity: 87 },
  { from: 9, to: 2, quantity: 9 },
  { from: 9, to: 3, quantity: 123 },
  { from: 9, to: 4, quantity: 376 },
  { from: 9, to: 5, quantity: 233 },
  { from: 9, to: 6, quantity: 199 },
  { from: 9, to: 7, quantity: 43 },
  { from: 9, to: 8, quantity: 90 },
  { from: 9, to: 9, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 9, to: 10, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 9, to: 11, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 9, to: 12, quantity: 4 },
  { from: 9, to: 13, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 9, to: 14, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 9, to: 15, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 10, to: 0, quantity: 23 },
  { from: 10, to: 1, quantity: 1 },
  { from: 10, to: 2, quantity: 9 },
  { from: 10, to: 3, quantity: 6 },
  { from: 10, to: 4, quantity: 197 },
  { from: 10, to: 5, quantity: 201 },
  { from: 10, to: 6, quantity: 66 },
  { from: 10, to: 7, quantity: 7 },
  { from: 10, to: 8, quantity: 143 },
  { from: 10, to: 9, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 10, to: 10, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 10, to: 11, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 10, to: 12, quantity: 1 },
  { from: 10, to: 13, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 10, to: 14, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 10, to: 15, quantity: 18 },
  { from: 11, to: 0, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 11, to: 1, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 11, to: 2, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 11, to: 3, quantity: 4 },
  { from: 11, to: 4, quantity: 67 },
  { from: 11, to: 5, quantity: 23 },
  { from: 11, to: 6, quantity: 221 },
  { from: 11, to: 7, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 11, to: 8, quantity: 4 },
  { from: 11, to: 9, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 11, to: 10, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 11, to: 11, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 11, to: 12, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 11, to: 13, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 11, to: 14, quantity: 3 },
  { from: 11, to: 15, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 12, to: 0, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 12, to: 1, quantity: 16 },
  { from: 12, to: 2, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 12, to: 3, quantity: 8 },
  { from: 12, to: 4, quantity: 412 },
  { from: 12, to: 5, quantity: 321 },
  { from: 12, to: 6, quantity: 100 },
  { from: 12, to: 7, quantity: 54 },
  { from: 12, to: 8, quantity: 89 },
  { from: 12, to: 9, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 12, to: 10, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 12, to: 11, quantity: 4 },
  { from: 12, to: 12, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 12, to: 13, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 12, to: 14, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 12, to: 15, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 13, to: 0, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 13, to: 1, quantity: 3 },
  { from: 13, to: 2, quantity: 30 },
  { from: 13, to: 3, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 13, to: 4, quantity: 80 },
  { from: 13, to: 5, quantity: 83 },
  { from: 13, to: 6, quantity: 20 },
  { from: 13, to: 7, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 13, to: 8, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 13, to: 9, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 13, to: 10, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 13, to: 11, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 13, to: 12, quantity: 1 },
  { from: 13, to: 13, quantity: 4 },
  { from: 13, to: 14, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 13, to: 15, quantity: 32 },
  { from: 14, to: 0, quantity: 30 },
  { from: 14, to: 1, quantity: 45 },
  { from: 14, to: 2, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 14, to: 3, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 14, to: 4, quantity: 486 },
  { from: 14, to: 5, quantity: 512 },
  { from: 14, to: 6, quantity: 89 },
  { from: 14, to: 7, quantity: 10 },
  { from: 14, to: 8, quantity: 188 },
  { from: 14, to: 9, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 14, to: 10, quantity: 8 },
  { from: 14, to: 11, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 14, to: 12, quantity: 4 },
  { from: 14, to: 13, quantity: 22 },
  { from: 14, to: 14, quantity: 12 },
  { from: 14, to: 15, quantity: 287 },
  { from: 15, to: 0, quantity: 30 },
  { from: 15, to: 1, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 15, to: 2, quantity: 8 },
  { from: 15, to: 3, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 15, to: 4, quantity: 275 },
  { from: 15, to: 5, quantity: 100 },
  { from: 15, to: 6, quantity: 45 },
  { from: 15, to: 7, quantity: 8 },
  { from: 15, to: 8, quantity: 87 },
  { from: 15, to: 9, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 15, to: 10, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 15, to: 11, quantity: 0 },
  { from: 15, to: 12, quantity: 8 },
  { from: 15, to: 13, quantity: 2 },
  { from: 15, to: 14, quantity: 310 },
  { from: 15, to: 15, quantity: 54 }
];

var totalCount = 0;
var matrix = [];

//Map list of data to matrix
flows.forEach(function(flow) {
  if (!matrix[flow.from]) {
    matrix[flow.from] = [];
  }
  matrix[flow.from][flow.to] = flow.quantity;
  totalCount += flow.quantity;
});

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////// Initiate Chord Diagram /////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
var size = 1000;
var margin = {
  top: 50,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 50
};
var width = size - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = size - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var innerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * .39;
var outerRadius = innerRadius * 1.08;
var focusedChordGroupIndex = null;

/*Initiate the SVG*/
//D3.js v3!
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left + width / 2) + "," + (margin.top + height / 2) + ")");

var chord = customChordLayout() //Using custom chord layout to order chords by adjacency so that they don't cross.
  .padding(0.02)
  .sortChords(d3.ascending) /*which chord should be shown on top when chords cross. Now the biggest chord is at the top*/
  .matrix(matrix);

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////// Draw outer Arcs /////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")
  .data(chord.groups)
  .enter().append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return "group " + locations[d.index].id;
  });

g.append("svg:path")
  .attr("class", "arc")
  .style("stroke", function(d) {
    return d3.rgb(locations[d.index].color).brighter();
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return locations[d.index].color;
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .on("click", function(d) {
    highlightChords(d.index)
  });

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////// Initiate Ticks //////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
var ticks = svg.selectAll("g.group").append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return "ticks " + locations[d.index].id;
  })
  .selectAll("g.ticks")
  .attr("class", "ticks")
  .data(groupTicks)
  .enter().append("svg:g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")" +
      "translate(" + outerRadius + 40 + ",0)";
  });

/*Append the tick around the arcs*/
ticks.append("svg:line")
  .attr("x1", 1)
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("x2", 8)
  .attr("y2", 0)
  .attr("class", "ticks")
  .style("stroke", "#FFF")
  .style("stroke-width", "1.5px");

/*Add the labels for the %'s*/
ticks.append("svg:text")
  .attr("x", 8)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("class", "tickLabels")
  .style("font-size", "10px")
  .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("fill", "#FFF")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)translate(-16)" : null;
  })
  .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.label;
  });

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////// Initiate Names //////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
g.append("svg:text")
  .each(function(d) {
    d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2;
  })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("class", "titles")
  .style("font-size", "14px")
  .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("fill", "#FFF")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")" +
      "translate(" + (innerRadius + 55) + ")" +
      (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
  })
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return locations[i].name;
  });

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////// Initiate inner chords /////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
var chords = svg.selectAll("path.chord")
  .data(chord.chords)
  .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("class", "chord")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return "chord chord-source-" + d.source.index + " chord-target-" + d.target.index;
  })
  .style("fill-opacity", "0.7")
  .style("stroke-opacity", "1")
  //Change the fill to reference the unique gradient ID
  //of the source-target combination
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return "url(#chordGradient-" + d.source.index + "-" + d.target.index + ")";
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d) {
    return "url(#chordGradient-" + d.source.index + "-" + d.target.index + ")";
  })
  //.style("stroke", function (d) { return d3.rgb(locations[d.source.index].color).brighter(); })
  //.style("fill", function (d) { return locations[d.source.index].color; })
  .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(innerRadius))
  .on("click", function() {
    showAllChords()
  });

//Cf https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2016/06/orientation-gradient-d3-chord-diagram
//Create a gradient definition for each chord
var grads = svg.append("defs").selectAll("linearGradient")
  .data(chord.chords)
  .enter().append("linearGradient")
  //Create a unique gradient id per chord: e.g. "chordGradient-0-4"
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return "chordGradient-" + d.source.index + "-" + d.target.index;
  })
  //Instead of the object bounding box, use the entire SVG for setting locations
  //in pixel locations instead of percentages (which is more typical)
  .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
  //The full mathematical formula to find the x and y locations
  .attr("x1", function(d, i) {
    return innerRadius * Math.cos((d.source.endAngle - d.source.startAngle) / 2 +
      d.source.startAngle - Math.PI / 2);
  })
  .attr("y1", function(d, i) {
    return innerRadius * Math.sin((d.source.endAngle - d.source.startAngle) / 2 +
      d.source.startAngle - Math.PI / 2);
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
    return innerRadius * Math.cos((d.target.endAngle - d.target.startAngle) / 2 +
      d.target.startAngle - Math.PI / 2);
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
    return innerRadius * Math.sin((d.target.endAngle - d.target.startAngle) / 2 +
      d.target.startAngle - Math.PI / 2);
  });

//Set the starting color (at 0%)
grads.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "0%")
  .attr("stop-color", function(d) {
    return locations[d.source.index].color;
  });

//Set the ending color (at 100%)
grads.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "100%")
  .attr("stop-color", function(d) {
    return locations[d.target.index].color;
  });

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////// Extra Functions /////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

/*Returns an array of tick angles and labels, given a group*/
function groupTicks(d) {
  var anglePerPerson = (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / d.value;
  var personsPerPercent = totalCount / 100;
  return d3.range(0, d.value, personsPerPercent).map(function(v, i) {
    return {
      angle: v * anglePerPerson + d.startAngle,
      label: i % 5 ? null : v / personsPerPercent + "%"
    };
  });
};

//Hides all chords except the chords connecting to the subgroup / location of the given index.
function highlightChords(index) {
  //If this subgroup is already highlighted, toggle all chords back on.
  if (focusedChordGroupIndex === index) {
    showAllChords();
    return;
  }

  hideAllChords();

  //Show only the ones with source or target == index
  d3.selectAll(".chord-source-" + index + ", .chord-target-" + index)
    .style("fill-opacity", "0.7")
    .style("stroke-opacity", "1");

  focusedChordGroupIndex = index;
}

function showAllChords() {
  svg.selectAll("path.chord")
    .style("fill-opacity", "0.7")
    .style("stroke-opacity", "1");

  focusedChordGroupIndex = null;
}

function hideAllChords() {
  svg.selectAll("path.chord")
    .style("fill-opacity", "0")
    .style("stroke-opacity", "0");
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////// Custom Chord Layout Function //////////////////
/////// Places the Chords in the visually best order ///////
///////////////// to reduce overlap ////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////// Slightly adjusted by Nadieh Bremer ////////////////
//////////////// VisualCinnamon.com ////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////// Original from the d3.layout.chord() function ////////
///////////////// from the d3.js library ///////////////////
//////////////// Created by Mike Bostock ///////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function customChordLayout() {
  var ε = 1e-6,
    ε2 = ε * ε,
    π = Math.PI,
    τ = 2 * π,
    τε = τ - ε,
    halfπ = π / 2,
    d3_radians = π / 180,
    d3_degrees = 180 / π;
  var chord = {},
    chords, groups, matrix, n, padding = 0,
    sortGroups, sortSubgroups, sortChords;

  function relayout() {
    var subgroups = {},
      groupSums = [],
      groupIndex = d3.range(n),
      subgroupIndex = [],
      k, x, x0, i, j;
    var numSeq;
    chords = [];
    groups = [];
    k = 0, i = -1;

    while (++i < n) {
      x = 0, j = -1, numSeq = [];
      while (++j < n) {
        x += matrix[i][j];
      }
      groupSums.push(x);
      //////////////////////////////////////
      ////////////// New part //////////////
      //////////////////////////////////////
      for (var m = 0; m < n; m++) {
        numSeq[m] = (n + (i - 1) - m) % n;
      }
      subgroupIndex.push(numSeq);
      //////////////////////////////////////
      //////////  End new part /////////////
      //////////////////////////////////////
      k += x;
    } //while

    k = (τ - padding * n) / k;
    x = 0, i = -1;
    while (++i < n) {
      x0 = x, j = -1;
      while (++j < n) {
        var di = groupIndex[i],
          dj = subgroupIndex[di][j],
          v = matrix[di][dj],
          a0 = x,
          a1 = x += v * k;
        subgroups[di + "-" + dj] = {
          index: di,
          subindex: dj,
          startAngle: a0,
          endAngle: a1,
          value: v
        };
      } //while

      groups[di] = {
        index: di,
        startAngle: x0,
        endAngle: x,
        value: (x - x0) / k
      };
      x += padding;
    } //while

    i = -1;
    while (++i < n) {
      j = i - 1;
      while (++j < n) {
        var source = subgroups[i + "-" + j],
          target = subgroups[j + "-" + i];
        if (source.value || target.value) {
          chords.push(source.value < target.value ? {
            source: target,
            target: source
          } : {
            source: source,
            target: target
          });
        } //if
      } //while
    } //while
    if (sortChords) resort();
  } //function relayout

  function resort() {
    chords.sort(function(a, b) {
      return sortChords((a.source.value + a.target.value) / 2, (b.source.value + b.target.value) / 2);
    });
  }
  chord.matrix = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return matrix;
    n = (matrix = x) && matrix.length;
    chords = groups = null;
    return chord;
  };
  chord.padding = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return padding;
    padding = x;
    chords = groups = null;
    return chord;
  };
  chord.sortGroups = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return sortGroups;
    sortGroups = x;
    chords = groups = null;
    return chord;
  };
  chord.sortSubgroups = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return sortSubgroups;
    sortSubgroups = x;
    chords = null;
    return chord;
  };
  chord.sortChords = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return sortChords;
    sortChords = x;
    if (chords) resort();
    return chord;
  };
  chord.chords = function() {
    if (!chords) relayout();
    return chords;
  };
  chord.groups = function() {
    if (!groups) relayout();
    return groups;
  };
  return chord;
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>

  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <div id="chart">
        <!--D3.js diagram goes here-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Thanks a ton for any hints or ideas!

Comment: Maybe following wonderful post provides some hints?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813723/change-and-transition-dataset-in-chord-diagram-with-d3/21923560#21923560

Comment: There is also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193272/preventing-d3-chords-from-overlapping) which seems to conclude there are no good solutions. And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645742/d3-chord-diagram-that-produces-parallel-ribbons) which might help.

Comment: Thanks very much for your links! However, I did already figure out the problem of chord ordering (my chords do no longer cross each other). They still do overlap, as in that the chord curves extend too far towards the center of the diagram. I'll add another picture to my post to try to illustrate the problem a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, solved my problem. Thanks to JohanC's comment of this post: [Change and transition dataset in chord diagram with D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813723/change-and-transition-dataset-in-chord-diagram-with-d3/21923560#21923560), it lead me towards the right direction.

My problem was solely the shape of the curves which d3's chord path generator generated. Thus I went and changed the svg path generator so that it shapes the curves to my liking. The default d3 v3 path generator uses quadratic bezier curves for the chords, where the middle control point is put at the center of the chord diagram. I changed the generator function to use cubic bezier curves instead, where the middle control points are placed between the inner ring and the center. The greater the angle between start- and endpoint, the closer the control points are to the center of the diagram, on a quadratic scale (in case anyone wishes an illustration or more elaborate explanation, feel free to comment)

Before (using d3.svg.chord()):
[image]

After (using custom generator):
[image]

**Code**
*Important: This probably only works with d3.v3!*

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////// Custom Chord Path Generator ///////////////////
///////// Uses cubic bezier curves with quadratic //////////
/////// spread of control points to minimise overlap ///////
////////////////// of adjacent chords. /////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////// Slightly adjusted by Severin Zahler ///////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////// Original from the d3.svg.chord() function //////////
///////////////// from the d3.js library ///////////////////
//////////////// Created by Mike Bostock ///////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function customChordPathGenerator() {
    var source = function(d) { return d.source; };
    var target = function(d) { return d.target; };
    var radius = function(d) { return d.radius; };
    var startAngle = function(d) { return d.startAngle; };
    var endAngle = function(d) { return d.endAngle; };

    function chord(d, i) {
        var s = subgroup(this, source, d, i),
            t = subgroup(this, target, d, i);

        var path = "M" + s.p0
            + arc(s.r, s.p1, s.a1 - s.a0) + (equals(s, t)
            ? curve(s.r, s.p1, s.a1, s.r, s.p0, s.a0)
            : curve(s.r, s.p1, s.a1, t.r, t.p0, t.a0)
            + arc(t.r, t.p1, t.a1 - t.a0)
            + curve(t.r, t.p1, t.a1, s.r, s.p0, s.a0))
            + "Z";

        return path;
    }

    function subgroup(self, f, d, i) {
        var subgroup = f.call(self, d, i),
            r = radius.call(self, subgroup, i),
            a0 = startAngle.call(self, subgroup, i) - (Math.PI / 2),
            a1 = endAngle.call(self, subgroup, i) - (Math.PI / 2);

        return {
            r: r,
            a0: a0,
            a1: a1,
            p0: [r * Math.cos(a0), r * Math.sin(a0)],
            p1: [r * Math.cos(a1), r * Math.sin(a1)]
        };
    }

    function equals(a, b) {
        return a.a0 == b.a0 && a.a1 == b.a1;
    }

    function arc(r, p, a) {
        return "A" + r + "," + r + " 0 " + +(a > Math.PI) + ",1 " + p;
    }

    function curve(r0, p0, a0, r1, p1, a1) {
        //////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////// New part //////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////
        var deltaAngle = Math.abs(mod((a1 - a0 + Math.PI), (2 * Math.PI)) - Math.PI);
        var radialControlPointScale = Math.pow((Math.PI - deltaAngle) / Math.PI, 2) * 0.9;
        var controlPoint1 = [p0[0] * radialControlPointScale, p0[1] * radialControlPointScale];
        var controlPoint2 = [p1[0] * radialControlPointScale, p1[1] * radialControlPointScale];
        var cubicBezierSvg = "C " + controlPoint1[0] + " " + controlPoint1[1] + ", " + controlPoint2[0] + " " + controlPoint2[1] + ", " + p1[0] + " " + p1[1];
        return cubicBezierSvg;
        //////////////////////////////////////
        //////////  End new part /////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////
    }

    function mod(a, n) {
        return (a % n + n) % n;
    }

    chord.radius = function(v) {
        if (!arguments.length) return radius;
            radius = typeof v === "function" ? v : function() { return v; };
        return chord;
    };

    chord.source = function(v) {
        if (!arguments.length) return source;
            source = typeof v === "function" ? v : function() { return v; };
        return chord;
    };

    chord.target = function(v) {
        if (!arguments.length) return target;
            target = typeof v === "function" ? v : function() { return v; };
        return chord;
    };

    chord.startAngle = function(v) {
        if (!arguments.length) return startAngle;
            startAngle = typeof v === "function" ? v : function() { return v; };
        return chord;
    };

    chord.endAngle = function(v) {
        if (!arguments.length) return endAngle;
            endAngle = typeof v === "function" ? v : function() { return v; };
        return chord;
    };

    return chord;
}
```

Complete diagram: https://jsfiddle.net/nbhodfas/